# How to emulate a switch on power line

Tags: power-supply, switches, dc

I have a circuit with two DC power lines coming from BAT1 (1A) & BAT2 (2A) (two outputs of a power bank). There is a sliding switch on the power line of BAT1. I would like to keep only one switch to control both power lines.

I have some N-Channel MOSFETs (RFP30N06LE), do you know a circuit that will allow me to open/close the power line of BAT2 using the state of power line of BAT1 ?

[image: Circuit]

For information, the charge on line 1 is an Arduino and a video camera, on line 2 its a DC motor and a servo motor.

The easiest solution seems to use relays but it looks like overkill to control 5V with 5V... It will also consume more power than the MOSFET I think. I would like to know if you have better solutions.

Comment: How about changing the switch to a DPST so it can switch both line itself?

Comment: For sure it is the easiest solution but I would prefer not damaging the body of my project by replacing the small switch by an other one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use low-side switching, you can use an N-channel MOSFET in this configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvXcOW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is added as a pull-down to ensure LOAD2 gets turned off when the switch is open. If LOAD1 has a low enough impedance to ground when off, you can omit R1.

If you must have high-side switches, the simplest configuration I can think of right now requires 2 P-channel MOSFETs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5qnJk.png)</sup>

If V1/V2 exceed the gate/source breakdown voltage, you can add another resistor R2 to form a divider with R1, or do something fancier like using a zener diode if V1/V2 can have different voltages. This doesn't appear to be the case for you so I've left them off.

This second solution has the added benefit that you can use a truly wimpy switch SW1 as LOAD1 and LOAD2 are directly driven through the MOSFETs.

As a side-note, you may need to add a reverse protection diode to protect the MOSFET from the inductive load.

Side-side note, since you have a microcontroller available, you could control the MOSFET from a microcontroller pin. This takes up an IO pin, but allows you to turn the other load on/off from code. This may or may not be desirable depending on your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks good. How to know if I need a low-side or high-side switching ?

If needed I have diodes.

I just found a circuit like your first one [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits#Using_a_FET), it looks good to me (I have what it need).

I really don't understand the danger/drawback of your first solution. Solution 2 seems good but I'll have to order new elements and it will take time :(

Comment: "Side-side note, since you have a microcontroller available, you could control the MOSFET from a microcontroller pin. This takes up an IO pin, but allows you to turn the other load on/off from code. This may or may not be desirable depending on your application." Here, I don't see usage where I would like to turn of my motors from my code.

Comment: I usually default to low-side switching for low-voltage electronics except in automotive applications because N-type transistors are generally better bang for the buck. At higher voltages, you need to really think about safety and usually this means a high switch, but this is by no means a definitive rule or even sufficient by itself for safety reasons. There are other reasons why you would pick one over the other, but they tend to be application-specific.

Comment: Thanks again ! Ok, I use 5V power so low-side switching  seems good for me. I have a problem with your conclusion: "There are other reasons why you would pick one over the other, but they tend to be application-specific". What can I miss ? Can I safely use the low-side schema based on the infos I give concerning the charges ? Thx again :-)

Comment: I don't see any major problems for you using a low-side switch. "Application specific reasons" is code for "I can't think of a reason right now, but you'll probably know when you see it" ;)

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot for your help, I'll try this circuit ASAP ! :)

Comment: Here is the full circuit: [Full schema](http://i.imgur.com/hlHLOOz.png). I have a problem, when the switch is open I have 2V in the motor controler input (L9110). Any idea ?

Comment: It is quite difficult to tell what is going on in your schematic. I highly recommend reading [these tips for drawing understandable schematics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics/28255#28255). As far as I can tell your MOSFET's are upside down. The source should be attached to ground, not the drain.

Comment: Oups, I made a mistake on my drawing (soldering is good), here is the new version with the MOSFET after a rotation: [new version](http://i.imgur.com/rBPn74g.png). I also notice that I have drawn a 10K resistor instead of a 100K like you said. Could it be the cause of the problems ?

Comment: Unlikely; that resistor is just there to give a well defined state for the gate. A 10k pull down just make the pull-down stronger, drawing more power. I have no idea what pin you are measuring or even if that is a problem.

Comment: I made the mesure between pin 3 & 4 on the L9110 (The motor controler). Moreover after some time with the switch open the MOTORS MOSFET is very hot. (No pb with the CAMERA MOSFET that was already in place).

Comment: Your motor driver appears to be in parallel with the MOSFET and the servo motor, but it's not at all obvious to me how to fix this because I don't understand your schematic. I recommend re-drawing your schematic using the tips found in the link I posted and asking a new question.

Comment: Done :) I post a new answer with the schematic.

Comment: You should post a new **question**, not new answer. Also, a servo motor and driver are not well approximated by a 2 terminal resistor.

Comment: You would prefer coils ?

Comment: Here it is http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182768/fail-circuit-with-n-mosfet-what-is-wrong :)

Comment: It looks like the problem comes from the motor driver, not the circuit. You got the solution ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @helloworld922 I made this circuit:
[image]

I have a problem with it, I get 2V on the **motor driver** when the **SW1** is open. Moreover the MOSFET **M1** became quite hot.

The goal was to use **M1** as switch for **BATT B** managed by **SW1**. Do you see any error that can cause my problem ?