# Fail circuit with N MOSFET, what is wrong?

Tags: mosfet, dc

I have a circuit with two DC power lines coming from **BATT A** (1A) & **BATT B** (2A) (two outputs of a power bank). There is a sliding switch on the power line of **BATT A**. I would like to keep only one switch to control both power lines.

I the following circuit with a N-Channel MOSFET ([RFP30N06LE](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf)) to be able to control the power line of **BATT B** using the state of power line of **BATT A** ?

[image: Circuit]

I have a problem with it, I get 2V on the **motor driver** when the **SW1** is open. Moreover the MOSFET **M1** became quite hot.

The goal was to use **M1** as switch for **BATT B** managed by **SW1**. Do you see any error that can cause my problem ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Missing information: 1 - FET datasheet.  No, we're not going to chase it down ourselves.  It's your job to provide a link.  2 - How much current do the "motor driver" and "servo motor" draw together worst case?

Comment: Check the FET datasheet. You may need 10V on the gate to turn it fully on. At 5V it may still be an amplifier, with Vds= 2V as you are seeing.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - By my reading of the data sheet, Vgs(th) is 2 volts, and it should be working fine. From Fig 10, a 5-volt gate and 2 volts Vds implies a load current of 50 amps.

Comment: @What: Vgs is not a particularly relevent spec.  It doesn't tell you what on resistance the FET will have at 5 V gate drive.

Comment: But Figure 10 does. At 5V Vgs, a 2-volt Vds and a 50 amp Id suggest about .04 ohms Rds.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all your answer. 

@Olin: Sorry, I forgot to give the link to the datasheet, I just add it to my question. The servo can draw 500mA & the motor 2A (BATT B can provide up to 2A).

#Others: I'm not so skilled with electronic, I don't know what to answer. From datasheet, Vgs=2V, Rds=0.047Ω. The MOSFET is supposed to support 60V, 30A.

Comment: Grounds not connected? nevermind I see in another answer this information. Perhaps it is indeed just the MOSFET you are using is not logic level. Get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If camera connects to servo driver and/or motor driver in any way, that is likely your problem- you are switching the low side of the latter.

A high side switch (lots of answers here illustrate the concept) uses two transistors- one if which would best be a p-channel MOSFET to switch the loads.

Edit: From your comments, it appears that the (unseen) Arduino is the problem, and because of the low-side switch as I speculated.

So, move over to a high-side switch and all will be well.

Comment: Hi, Camera & motors are not supposed to be connected. Camera is only connected to the MOSFET gate to trigger it. Maybe I don't really understand your answer, could you explain me what you mean ?

Comment: Most likely, something is causing the MOSFET gate to be >0V when that switch is open. Maybe there are batteries in the camera and it is feeding out voltage, maybe there's something else going on. Whatever it is, your schematic does not represent accurately what is going on (the three loads shown as isolated resistors are not behaving as such).

Comment: Nop, no other batteries than BATT A & B. But all GND are connected. If I understand you well, soldering this exact circuit must works. I also have an Arduino powered by BATT A that control all my stuff: the motor driver, a MOSFET that control the camera, the servo motor... Is it possible that the power comes from BATT B to the servo control pin of the arduino and go back in the circuit (BATT A side throw the camera MOSFET for instance)... ? Can a diode in the the servo wire fix it ?

Comment: After some other tests it looks like the circuit drawn works well, problem comes when I plug the arduino... :-(

Comment: My motor controler is the [HG7881](https://www.bananarobotics.com/shop/HG7881-(L9110)-Dual-Channel-Motor-Driver-Module) including 2 [L9110](https://www.creatroninc.com/upload/L9110%20Datasheet.pdf). It looks like the problem is here. When I do not connect the 2 pins of command all is fine, when I connect the 2 pins of command I have the leak...